# How can I find IDs of DIVS, and assign those names as classes to other DIVS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I'm fairly new to jquery and cannot figure this out. I have 3 divs with different id's but all start with "sharedform". I want to loop through those divs, grab each id and assign it as an identifying class to the 'slideHead' div preceding each. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

HMTL:

```
<div class="slideHead">
</div>
<div class="drawer">
  <div id="sharedform.upload_image">
          <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slideHead">
</div>
<div class="drawer">
   <div id="sharedform.Event">
       <p></p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="slideHead">
</div>
<div class="drawer">
    <div id="sharedform.BackGround_All">
        <p></p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

jquery:

```
var $getclass = $(".drawer");
    addclass = $getclass.find('[id^="sharedform"]').attr('id');
$(".slideHead").addClass(addclass);
```

Comment: `.slidehead` is the selector for *all* elements with the `slidehead` class. You want to find each class and for each one add the class to the nearest sibling going up the DOM. So you'd want an `each` in there.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, just not sure where.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

```
// get all elements whose id starts with 'sharedform', iterate over that collection:
$('div[id^=sharedform]').each(function (){
    // find the parent of the 'this' element:
    $(this).parent()
    // find the previous element, if it matches the passed-in selector:
    .prev('.slideHead')
    // add the id of the element we initially selected as a class:
    .addClass(this.id);
});
```

```js
$('div[id^=sharedform]').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().prev('.slideHead').addClass(this.id);
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.slideHead {
  background-color: #f00;
}
.slideHead.sharedform\.something {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideHead"></div>
<div>
  <div id="sharedform.something">some text in the div</div>
</div>
```

But note that those class-names are problematic, given the inclusion of a period (`.`) in the `id`.

Comment: Right. Unfortunately those class-names are tied to deeper programming that isn't accessible.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$('[id^=sharedform]').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('.drawer').prev().addClass( this.id );
});
```

```js
$('[id^=sharedform]').each(function() {
        $(this).closest('.drawer').prev().addClass( this.id );
    });

var newHTML = $('body').html(),
    out = $('<pre/>', {class:'out'}).appendTo( 'body' );

out.text( 'NEW HTML\n' + newHTML );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideHead">
</div>
<div class="drawer">
  <div id="sharedform.upload_image">
          <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slideHead">
</div>
<div class="drawer">
   <div id="sharedform.Event">
       <p></p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="slideHead">
</div>
<div class="drawer">
    <div id="sharedform.BackGround_All">
        <p></p>
    </div>
 </div>
```